# True concurrency on a collection in Windows WF 4.5

Tags: c#, concurrency, workflow-foundation-4

I am modifying an existing Windows Workflow Foundation project that was previous coded to run everything synchronously. However, as the data set grew this needed to change to meet performance requirements.

**What I have:**
[image]

Inside the workflow I have a parent Sequence Workflow that contains a few elementary workflows that basically set a few services up and prepares them to run. **I then have the bulk of the workflow's work**, which consists of a ForEach Workflow that operates on a collection of about 15000 items that take about 1-3 seconds per item to process (timings are around 70% CPU, 10% network latency, 20% database querying/access). Obviously this takes WAYYYY too long. I need to improve this time by about a factor of 5 (takes around 5-6 hours, need to get to about 1 hour)

**Delima:**

I have never worked with Windows Workflows before this project so I very unfamiliar with how to achieve otherwise simple implementations of concurrent execution on a collection.

**Ideas:**

I read about the different Workflow Activities and decided that a [ParallelForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee849842.aspx) Workflow Activity would probably be the way to go. My idea was that I would just switch out my ForEach Workflow Activity with the ParallelForEach Workflow activity and achieve concurrency in the way the Parallel.Foreach() works in the Task Parallel Library. Unfortunately, that does not seem to be how the ParallelForEach Workflow Activity is implemented. Instead of scheduling the work to be done on each collection across multiple threads and context switching when another thread was waiting, the ParallelForEach Workflow Activity seems to just put each iteration in a stack and operates on them almost syncrounously, unless the body of the workflow is "Idle" (which I do not believe is the same thing as "waiting" on I/O. It seems to be an explicit state that needs to be set on a workflow activity-per MSDN:

> ParallelForEach enumerates its values and schedules the Body for
>   every value it enumerates on. It only schedules the Body. How the body
>   executes depends on whether the Body goes idle.
>    If the Body does not
>   go idle, it executes in a reverse order because the scheduled
>   activities are handled as a stack, the last scheduled activity
>   executes first. For example, if you have a collection of {1,2,3,4}in
>   ParallelForEach and use a WriteLine as the body to write the value
>   out. You have 4, 3, 2, 1 printed out in the console. This is because
>   WriteLine does not go idle so after 4 WriteLine activities got
>   scheduled, they executed using a stack behavior (first in last out).
>
> But if you have activities in the Body that can go idle, like a
>   Receive activity or Delay activity. Then there is no need to wait for
>   them to complete. ParallelForEach goes to the next scheduled body
>   activity and try to execute it. If that activity goes idle too,
>   ParallelForEach moves on again the next body activity.

**Where I am now:**

When running my "idea" above with the ParallelForEach Workflow Activity, I achieve about the same running time as the normal ForEach Workflow Activity. I was considering making the underlying BeginWorkflow method async but I'm not sure if that will be a good idea or not with how Windows WF operates.

**I need your help:**

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve the results that I am trying to get to? Is there another way to implement something that would execute the body of the foreach workflow in parallel on as many threads as possible? I have 8 logical processor and I want to take advantage of all of them sense each iteration of the collection is independent from the others.

**Any Ideas??**

Comment: If most of time is because of I/O then to make it parallel won't give you such big improvement...

Comment: True, but I have coded the implementations of those methods to use Async/Await so the thread is freed up. However, since they are all operating on the same thread, this does not seem to help because even though the thread is free, the next iteration of the body does not execute. I believe this has to do more with how the Workflow scheduler is implemented.

Comment: 1.5 x 15000 = 6 hours and 15 minutes. Or is the 1.5 not a correct average?

Comment: Also: It might be an option to reuse service proxies across work items. Instantiating a proxy and channel sometimes has a lot of overhead

Comment: Not a correct average. Depending on the content of each iteration timing can be between 5 and 10 hours. I was planning for the worst case.

Comment: Yes, I could do that but that doesn't seem to be where the time is spent. I am not initiating the services for each iteration. They are initialized and set up outside of the loop. I only have to call them to get specific data per each work item.

Comment: Have you tested your endpoint bottleneck? If you switch to a concurrent model, that 1-2 seconds per item might end up being more like 10-20s per item depending on your endpoint. It's happened to me before. I'd do some tests to ensure the throughput of your endpoint first. Otherwise, all of this might be in vain.

Comment: Yes, I've tested it in a seperate project that was not implemented using the workflows. A simple TPL Parallel.Foreach loop worked wonderfully but the project requires using the workflows to work with our 1000+ unit tests and other things. I am trying to implement the simplest solution that will achieve the biggest returns.

Comment: I do not understand. If most of body is spent in I/O and that resource is shared then why it has to do more in parallel and/or different threads? If 99% is there then you will not gain more than 1% unless you improve i/o performance. Caching? Prefetching? Ram disk? It matters very little anything else,  which thread is used/reused and so on. Unless I'm missing something important...

Comment: I was wrong about the I/0 @AdrianoRepetti, It's about 70% CPU maybe 10% network latency and 20% I/0 from the database access

Comment: My point @AdrianoRepetti is that when the thread is waiting on the I/O I would like it to start working on another interation of the body instead of sitting there and doing nothing.

Comment: Now I understand, if most of time is not doing I/O then you have chances to improve but...1000%...no, no more than code you may parallelize.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I agree that I will not get 1000% from just the parallelism. However, I was hoping to get about 400% with the parallelism by at least splitting most of the work between 4-8 threads on a quad core machine with hyperthreading. I realize that I will have to do more with the algorithms to reduce the timing.

Comment: I would be happy with cutting the time in half @AdrianoRepetti, what do you see in the picture that cannot be fully parallelized? All the work is basically done in the "RunPolicyWorkflow" Activity. I can take the other items out if it would matter.

Comment: Let me express better (sorry I'm using phone and I'm somehow lazy to write). Wf is single threaded, as you know you will go to *parallel* when an activity idle. I/O will idle but that's only your 20%. At some point you won't use more cores. You won't even gain more than half of your country time. If you write it in *code* then you may truly go parallel but not here. Only serious chance is to greatly improve activities code or algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The Workflow runtime is single threaded. To truly do parallel work, you have to manage your own threads (somehow). My guess is that your activities are simply doing their thing in the Execute method and the runtime will only allow one Execute at a time.

Here is the code for a NonblockingNativeActivity class. It has been useful for us, I hope it helps you as well. Use this as the base class for your activities, instead of overriding Execute, override ExecuteNonblocking. You can also override PrepareToExecute and AfterExecute if you need to work with the Workflow runtime but, those will be single threaded.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Activities.Hosting;
using System.Activities;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sample.Activities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class Non-Blocking Native Activity
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class NonblockingNativeActivity : NativeActivity
    {
        private Variable<NoPersistHandle> NoPersistHandle { get; set; }
        private Variable<Bookmark> Bookmark { get; set; }

        private Task m_Task;
        private Bookmark m_Bookmark;
        private BookmarkResumptionHelper m_BookmarkResumptionHelper;

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the activity to induce idle. 
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool CanInduceIdle
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prepars for Execution
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        protected virtual void PrepareToExecute(
            NativeActivityContext context)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes a Non-blocking Activity
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract void ExecuteNonblocking();

        /// <summary>
        /// After Execution Completes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        protected virtual void AfterExecute(
            NativeActivityContext context)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the Activity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {

            //
            //  We must enter a NoPersist zone because it looks like we're idle while our
            //  Task is executing but, we aren't really
            //
            NoPersistHandle noPersistHandle = NoPersistHandle.Get(context);
            noPersistHandle.Enter(context);

            //
            //  Set a bookmark that we will resume when our Task is done
            //
            m_Bookmark = context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkResumptionCallback);
            this.Bookmark.Set(context, m_Bookmark);
            m_BookmarkResumptionHelper = context.GetExtension<BookmarkResumptionHelper>();

            //
            //  Prepare to execute
            //
            PrepareToExecute(context);

            //
            //  Start a Task to do the actual execution of our activity
            //
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            m_Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ExecuteNonblocking, tokenSource.Token);
            m_Task.ContinueWith(TaskCompletionCallback);
        }

        private void TaskCompletionCallback(Task task)
        {
            if (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                task.Wait();
            }

            //
            //  Resume the bookmark
            //
            m_BookmarkResumptionHelper.ResumeBookmark(m_Bookmark, null);
        }


        private void BookmarkResumptionCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object value)
        {
            var noPersistHandle = NoPersistHandle.Get(context);

            if (m_Task.IsFaulted)
            {
                //
                //  The task had a problem
                //
                Console.WriteLine("Exception from ExecuteNonBlocking task:");
                Exception ex = m_Task.Exception;
                while (ex != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                }

                //
                // If there was an exception exit the no persist handle and rethrow.
                //
                if (m_Task.Exception != null)
                {
                    noPersistHandle.Exit(context);
                    throw m_Task.Exception;
                }
            }

            AfterExecute(context);

            noPersistHandle.Exit(context);
        }

        //
        //  TODO: How do we want to handle cancelations?  We can pass a CancellationToekn to the task
        //  so that we cancel the task but, maybe we can do better than that?
        //
        /// <summary>
        /// Abort Activity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        protected override void Abort(NativeActivityAbortContext context)
        {
            base.Abort(context);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cancels the Activity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        protected override void Cancel(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            base.Cancel(context);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers Activity Metadata
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="metadata"></param>
        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
            this.NoPersistHandle = new Variable<NoPersistHandle>();
            this.Bookmark = new Variable<Bookmark>();
            metadata.AddImplementationVariable(this.NoPersistHandle);
            metadata.AddImplementationVariable(this.Bookmark);
            metadata.RequireExtension<BookmarkResumptionHelper>();
            metadata.AddDefaultExtensionProvider<BookmarkResumptionHelper>(() => new BookmarkResumptionHelper());
        }
    }
}
```