# How to execute collection item concurrently

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I am developing windows workflow application. I have a collection of items and i need to process each item in the collection concurrently. Below is just the Pseudo code of Activities in the workflow

```
[Receive Message]

[Send Message]

[GetItemsFromDB]

[For Each Item]
{
  [Sequence] // for each Item i want to process this sequence concurrently
  {
       [Process Item]

       [Call Some API]

       [Receive Message]    
   }
}
```

the WWF has `ParallelForEach<T>` activity, However this activity does not process each item in the collection concurrently. It process next item in the collection only if any Activity inside body goes idle. So in the above example if i use `ParallelForEach<T>` then 
if `[Call Some API]` goes idle then only it will process next item in the collection.  [More Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990691/true-concurrency-on-a-collection-in-windows-wf-4-5)

I want the the block of sequence to execute concurrently for each item? 
How to i do that? any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the question that you linked answer your question? Workflow is single threaded, you have to deal with that. If your work can be done asynchronously, you should use AsyncCodeActivity. If not, the question that you linked has code that makes it easy to create non-blocking activities.